# How to read text that is under #shadow-root (user-agent) (Java-Selenium)

Tags: java, selenium, user-agent, shadow-dom

I am trying to find a text which falls under #shadow-root (user-agent). I tried multiple solutions I could find here, but none of them worked for me.Tried to use JavascriptExecutor. But it didn't work.
I am using selenium in Java language

Requirement: get the First and Last name and print it.
First Name: TEST and Last Name: USER is coming under #shadow-root (user-agent)

Below is the HTML

```
 <div class="form-group 
    required">
    <label class="form-control-label" for="firstName">
        First Name
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" data-missing-error="Please enter a value for Name" data-pattern-mismatch="Only letters, numbers, hyphens and apostrophes are allowed in someone's first name" data-range-error="Must be 30 characters or less." name="dwfrm_profile_customer_firstname" required="" aria-required="true" value="TEST" maxlength="30" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9-'][A-Za-z0-9-' ]*$">
    #shadow-root (user-agent)
   <div> TEST</div>
   </input>
    <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
</div>

<div class="form-group
    required">
    <label class="form-control-label" for="lastName">
        Last Name
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" data-missing-error="Please enter a value for Surname" data-pattern-mismatch="Only letters, numbers, hyphens and apostrophes are allowed in someone's last name" data-range-error="Must be 30 characters or less." name="dwfrm_profile_customer_lastname" required="" aria-required="true" value="USER" maxlength="30" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9-'][A-Za-z0-9-' ]*$">
   #shadow-root (user-agent)
    <div> TEST</div>[![enter image description here][1]][1]
    </input>
    <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Your code trials?

Comment: @Arjun can you add javascript you have used to reach shadow DOM ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 WebElement shadowHost = driver.findElement(By.id("firstname"));
 SearchContext shadowRoot = (SearchContext) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver)
.executeScript("return.argument[0].shadowRoot",shadowHost);

 String textFName = shadowRoot.findElement(By.tagName("div")).getText();


 WebElement shadowHostL = driver.findElement(By.id("lastName"));
 SearchContext shadowRootL = (SearchContext) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver)
.executeScript("return.argument[0].shadowRoot",shadowHostL);

 String textFName = shadowRootL.findElement(By.tagName("div")).getText();
```

maven dependency to add

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it didn't work for me. It is showing error under getShadowRoot(); "The method getShadowRoot() is undefined for the type WebElement".
I added the maven dependency to pom.xml.
Let me try to play around  a little bit and find the reason for error.

Comment: Ok I will try to run with other shadow Dom example and i will edit the answer

Comment: @Arjun - Answer is updated please check now, once

Comment: issue happened because getShadowRoot returns SearchContext and not WebDriver